# Converting a list of Points to an Array in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, paint

I'm currently trying to make a simple paint program in C# using a Windows Forms Application.  When converting my list of Points to an Array using the ToArray function, I'm getting a generic "ArgumentException was unhandled: Parameter is invalid" error.  I know I've done this before and it's worked fine, is there something special about the DrawLines function that I'm not aware of?  Below is the code, with the line in question being the last line in the panel1_Paint event.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetSig
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool paint = false;
    List<Point> myPointList = new List<Point>();

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = true;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (paint)
        {
            myPointList.Add(e.Location);
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = false;
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, myPointList.ToArray());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please remove all code that is not related to this question.

Comment: Try to create an array using Point[] array = myPointList.ToArray() and see what's inside. Maybe you'll find something odd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't draw lines without at least two points :)

```
if (myPointList.Count >= 2)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, myPointList.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for the help. It's funny how you forget the simplest things sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/7ewkcdb3.aspx):

> The first two points in the array specify the first line.

You need minimum two points in your `Array`.

Comment: The funny thing is, that the documentation doesn't mention about `ArgumentExeption` that in fact occurs there. It only says about `ArgumentNullException`...

Comment: @user2091198: After adding first point to the list, you're calling `Invalide` method which can induce `Paint` handler prior to next `MouseMove`. Use the `if (myPointList.Count >= 2)` before you invoke `DrawLines` as wrote ken2k in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that exception is not coming from the call to `ToArray` but from `e.Graphics.DrawLines`.